# Image with zoomed in border

Tags: css, image

I have a grid with lots of images with a mock-up html like the below:

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <img src="image.jpg" style="width: auto;" />
<div>
```

The problem is, the container div has a fixed width, and the width of the images differ between them, so I'm ending up with some containers with a white "padding" in the left and right sides of their inner image, because their inner image don't fit exactly the container width. I would like to make something similar to the image below, which is, when the image don't fit the width, I show a zoomed border in both sides.

[image: Image with zoomed border]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by inserting two images into each wrapper. One for the blurry background, one for the main image. Also, instead of using `<img>` tags, we use regular `<div>`s to have greater flexibility over the display of the image.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="background" style="background-image: url('...')"></div>
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url('...')"></div>
</div>
```

The wrapper must be a positioned element (i.e. `position` is set to anything but `static`), so that the children who are given `position: absolute;` will be positioned relative to the wrapper. The wrapper must also hide any overflow.

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative; /* Required */
  overflow: hidden;   /* Required */
  width: 400px;       /* Arbitrary */
  height: 500px;      /* Arbitrary */
}
```

Next, the children elements will both be positioned absolutely and made to cover the entire width and height of the wrapper. You must make sure that the `<div class="background">` comes before the `<div class="image">` in the HTML, or you will have to explicitly set `z-index` on each element in the CSS to ensure the `<div class="image">` is rendered on top.

```
/* Required */
.background,
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Now for the `div.background`, we will enlarge it to be 1.5x wider than the container, add a filter to blur the image and reduce the opacity slightly. You can tweak these to achieve the effect you want.

```
/* Personal Preference */
.background {
  background-size: 150% auto;
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

When setting the `background-size` of the `div.background`, make sure you only specify a size in one dimension, so that the image maintains its aspect ratio. e.g.:

```
/* Good */
.background {
  background-size: 200% auto;
}
.background {
  background-size: auto 200%;
}

/* Bad */
.background {
  background-size: 200% 200%;
}
```

Finally for the `div.image`, we just need to tell it how to scale the main image. These two options both preserve the aspect ratio of the image, but provide different sizing results:

```
.image {    
  /* Will only scale as large as the image itself */
  background-size: auto;
}

/* OR */

.image {    
  /* Scales until image hits one of the sides of the container */
  background-size: contain;    
}
```

Bringing it all together for an example:

```css
body {
  background: #222; 
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background,
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.background {
  background-size: 150% auto;
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.image {
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div 
   class="background" 
   style="background-image: url('https://loremflickr.com/250/500/face')"
  ></div>

  <div 
   class="image" 
   style="background-image: url('https://loremflickr.com/250/500/face')"
  ></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot!